# Accessing Facebook Pages ratings through Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am trying to access the ratings of a particular establishment by querying the FB Graph api using the [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) Ruby wrapper.

```
fb_client = FbGraph::Page.fetch('AnticaPesaBrooklyn', :access_token => "ACCESS_TOKEN")
```

However the information I get back does not contain the rating of the restaurant I am querying. How can I access the rating from this Facebook page?

Comment: do you own the page?

Comment: No I do not own the page, its a public facebook page for a restaurant.

Comment: in that case, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get ratings/review with a Page Access Token of that Page, and you only get a Page Token if you got a role in the Page (Admin/Moderator/...).

Comment: hmm...why wouldn't they provide the rating score of a page. weird

Comment: it is not that weird imho. ratings/reviews are none of your business if you do not own the page. but i think access to feed and photos of pages should be restricted to page owners too, actually.

Comment: Ratings of a restaurant (for example) is something that is viewed by the public therefore it is my business since i am trying to access information about the "quality" of the restaurant

Comment: public on facebook does not mean it is available for everyone with the api ;)

Comment: anyway, that is how it is. you do need a page token for ratings/reviews.